# Elasticsearch apply startswith regex on ids filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm filtering the documents by ids

Ex

```
   "filter": {
      "ids": {
        "values": ["1", "2", "3"]
    }
}
```

But i want to apply regex on below ids like below

```
  "filter": {
    "ids": {
        "values": ["1*", "2*", "3*"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with regex, performance can tank really fast if you do it wrong. From your example, it seems like you might want a [prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) instead?

That said, this should work:

```
  "filter": {
    "regexp": {
      "ids": "<regex_here>"
    }
  }
```

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html

Also, it seems like your `ids` field is an analyzed field, which seems odd to me.

Comment: it didnt woked..i think regex cant be applied for values.only for one value we can apply regex.

Comment: Your `ids` regex can be expressed as `(1|2|3).*`